# Verify a function is called from another function mockito

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have a class in which I would like to verify method calls

Here is a representation of my class :

```
public class MyClass {

    public void method1(String id) {
        MyClass inst = this.getParticularInstance(id);
        if(inst != null) {
            inst.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public MyClass getParticularInstance(String id) {
        // return a particular object or null
    }

    public void doSomething(String id) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In particular, I would like to make sure that when I call method1, getParticularInstance is called, and depending of the result, doSomething is called or not.

Is it possible to test such a code with Mockito, and if yes is it the right way ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to verify `doSomething` also?

Comment: Thank you for answer, I think the spy is what I need. Indeed as you just pointed out, I would like also to verify `doSomething`. I know it is possible to return a specific value with a mock, but I don't know if it is works the same way with a spy.

Comment: you can use `when(myClass.getParticularInstance(id)).thenReturn(mockedClass)` and `verify(mockedClass).doSomething(id)`

Comment: Does the method `doSomething()` exist in `MyClass`  or other class?

Comment: It exists in `MyClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy the MyClass and use `verify()` to verify the method invocation

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myClass = spy(new MyClass());
    }

    public void testMethod1() {
        // Arrange
        String id = "id1";

        // Act
        myClass.method1(id);

        // Assert
        verify(myClass).getParticularInstance(id);
    }
}
```